# How can I verify I'm using SSL to connect to mysql?

Tags: mysql, ssl

I have configured my server to allow SSL, and have modified my client ~/.my.cnf so I use SSL:

```
[client]
ssl
ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ssl-ca=~/certs/ca-cert.pem
```

When I log in with my client and view the status, it lists a cipher on the SSL line:

```
mysql> \s
--------------
SSL:            Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

Without installing something like wireshark to verify that the connection is secure, can I assume that I'm connecting via SSL based on this information?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the client, just run `status`.  If this connection is using SSL, you'll get something interesting in the SSL row.

```
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.30, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:      12
Current database:
Current user:       replicator@domU-12-31-39-10-54-BD.compute-1.internal
SSL:            Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.5.30-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     boston.hugskeep.wstudent.com via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         44 min 49 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 16  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 34  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 27  Queries per second avg: 0.005
--------------

mysql>
```

If this connection is not using SSL, you'll get:

```
SSL:            Not in use
```

You can also use:

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
+---------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name | Value              |
+---------------+--------------------+
| Ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA |
+---------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

But I think the first is more attractive, and sure easier to type.

Comment: `show status like 'Ssl_version'` can also be useful to determine the SSL/TLS protocol version being used.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to do this for a specific user. not just the current user? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203365/how-to-check-if-a-user-requires-ssl-in-mysql/56203435#56203435

Comment: I am not sure this has been changed now. For me even I am not using SSL, it shows ```SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA``` for me.

Answer (score 5):

Force SSL per user:

```
alter user 'my_user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
mysql> \s
```

Answer (score 3):

This is applicable to MariaDB (haven't tried it in pure MySQL):

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u testuser --ssl
```

The `--ssl` option will tell you if SSL is enabled. If it is disabled, the command will return "*not in use*"

Comment: ```WARNING: --ssl is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use --ssl-mode instead.``` MySQL 5.6.4

Answer (score 3):

The `status` command doesn't tell you if the connection is using SSL. Clients can disable using SSL from their side.

Use `show session status` and look for `Ssl_accepts` and `Ssl_finished_accepts` to find the number of connections using SSL.
These numbers increase when a new connection is made to the MySQL server using SSL.

Note that the variable `Ssl_client_connects` reflects the number of SSL connection attempts to an SSL-enabled replication source server, and has nothing to do with client applications connecting to the MySQL server that are using SSL.

See [Ssl_client_connects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Ssl_client_connects) (MySQL Documentation)

Most client applications (e.g. a PHP application) do not automatically use SSL connections when connecting to a database server. Most of the times you have to perform additional steps to securely connect to a remote database.

One of the easiest ways to ensure all connections to your database use a secure connection, is to require secure transport altogether. For MySQL you can use `SET GLOBAL require_secure_transport=1;`. Once enabled, any insecure connection will fail.

Answer (score 3):

**OFFICIAL SOLUTION ACCORDING TO MYSQL WEBSITE**

Run this in the session you want to verify:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.session_status 
> WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('Ssl_version','Ssl_cipher');
> ```

If you get the cipher and version strings, then the connection is encrypted. If it is not encrypted, you will get empty strings.

*Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html*

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.6.4

I am not sure this

> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';

has been changed in later versions. For me even if I am not using SSL, it shows `SSL: Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA` for me.

You can use following to get confirmed SSL is using or not.

```
ubuntu@ip-111-22-3-444:~$ mysql -h 111.22.3.444 -u dbuser --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY -p
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: CA certificate is required if ssl-mode is VERIFY_CA or VERIFY_IDENTITY
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Mysql Workbench:**

If you are connected to the server with Mysql Workbench you can see the SSL status variable in `Status and System Variable` section under `SSL` category-

[image]

*If SSL_Cipher value is blank that means SSL is not enabled*.

In my case: Yes, SSL is enabled.

Comment: Your screenshot show 'Ssl_client_connects', '0'. It means that no one is currently connected using ssl, including you. So even though you enable SSL you are still not using it, right?